# Inheriting raw types w/ conflicting generic super-interfaces

Tags: java, generics, intellij-idea

I've come across an interesting bit of Java code that IntelliJ flags as an error, but which `javac` accepts as legal.  Either IntelliJ is wrong, and the code is legal, or the compiler is "wrong", whether due to a bug or an intentional relaxation of rules.

I like to think I understand the Java type system *pretty* well, and my own reasoning leads me to suspect that IntelliJ is wrong and `javac` is right.  However, I have a heck of a time grokking the JLS, and I'd like to know for sure.

Before we get into the problematic code, let's look at some *similar* code that is **definitely illegal**:

```java
interface A<T> {}
interface X extends A<String> {}
interface Y extends A<Object> {}

interface Z extends X, Y {} // COMPILE ERROR
```

As I would expect, both IntelliJ and `javac` **correctly** flag this as an error: *'A' cannot be inherited with different type arguments: 'java.lang.String' and 'java.lang.Object'*.

No problem there.  But what if we make `X` and `Y` generic, with `Z` extending their **raw form**?

```java
interface X<T> extends A<String> {}
interface Y<T> extends A<Object> {}

interface Z extends X, Y {}  // OK according to javac, ERROR according to IntelliJ
```

Here, IntelliJ eagerly reports the same error it did for the first snippet, but `javac` happily accepts the code as written.

My understanding is that raw types are *recursively* erased, meaning all superclasses and superinterfaces of the original type are replaced with *their* recursively erased forms, and so on.  Thus, in the problematic code, `Z` ends up extending (raw) `A` via both `X` and `Y`, as opposed to first example, in which `Z` extends `A<String>` via `X` and `A<Object>` via `Y`.

If that is indeed the case, then I would conclude that IntelliJ is wrong, and `javac` is correct: the second code snippet is legal.

What say you, experts of Stack Overflow?

Comment: As a note, Eclipse also happily accepts the second snippet.

Comment: Looks like an Intellij bug to me; you should submit a report.

Comment: @Jacob I agree, and I’ve already written one up.  I just wanted to get confirmation first.

Comment: I have submitted a [but report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-186271) for this issue.

Comment: @MikeStrobel it's a bu**g** report

Comment: @Eugene <homer>D'OH</homer>

Comment: :) may I salute you on a very interesting first question? at least, it's my second day reading the spec...

Comment: Hey, you can salute me for whatever you like :).  And yeah, my biggest problem with the JLS is that I can't ever consult it without going down a rabbit hole that eats up my entire afternoon.  That's *partly* because actually locating all the sections relevant to a question requires reading an awful lot of it, but also because there's so much interesting stuff to get sidetracked on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The spec says in [JLS-8.1.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.5):

> A class may not at the same time be a subtype of two interface types which are different parameterizations of the same generic interface (§9.1.2), or a subtype of a parameterization of a generic interface and a raw type naming that same generic interface, or a compile-time error occurs.

Note that it makes a special note of the case of *"a subtype of a parameterization of a generic interface and a raw type naming that same generic interface"*, which would translate to something like `interface Z extends A<String>, A {}`. The case of 2 raw superinterfaces is not mentioned.

Furthermore, the spec gives this example:

> ```
> interface I<T> {}
> class B implements I<Integer> {}
> class C extends B implements I<String> {}
> ```
>
> *Class C causes a compile-time error because it attempts to be a subtype of both `I<Integer>` and `I<String>`.*

The problem is that `A` is extended with *different* type arguments, if `X` and `Y` both were to extend `A<Object>` in your first snippet that also compiles.

[JLS-4.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) says (as you already mentioned):

> The superclasses (respectively, superinterfaces) of a raw type are the erasures of the superclasses (superinterfaces) of any of the parameterizations of the generic type.

That means that `Z` extends the raw type `A` twice, *not* `A` with different parametrizations. Moreover, it is fine for a class to have the same (indirect) superinterface twice (see the second example in [JLS-8.1.5-2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.5)).

So I conclude that Intellij is wrong here.

Comment: Thank you, Jorn.  I agree with your interpretation of the spec.

Comment: @JornVernee `or a subtype of a parameterization of a generic interface and a raw type naming that **same** generic interface`, shouldn't your example be `interface Z extends X<String>, X {}`?

Comment: @Eugene Oh yeah, my bad. I just changed it to `interface Z extends A<String>, A {}`. The idea was that through `X` it would indirectly extend `A<String>`. And through `Y` it would extends `A`. But now that you mention it, I think it has the raw `A` as a super type in both cases, since once `A` is raw, it's always raw?

Comment: @JornVernee when we say `interface Z extends X, Y {}` the Spec does not cover it IMO as it specifically says **a class** may not at the same time... not an interface. it could be a simple omission, I can't tell. About the thing that you mention, I don't think so. A raw type != a type without any type declarations to begin with. So for the second example, the spec saying `The superclasses (respectively, superinterfaces) of a raw type are the erasures of the superclasses (superinterfaces) of any of the parameterizations of the generic type` is just a way to say that if `X` is raw, `A` is raw too

Comment: @JornVernee So to me, you are absolutely correct, in the sense that `Z` will extends the raw type `A` twice, indirectly, which again is allowed. In the first example `X` and `Y` are not raw to begin with, so all this does not even apply, thus again, you are correct, that `Z` extends `A` with *different* parametrization types, which, by the spec, is disallowed. Now, how to make any sense from a practical point, is beyond me and I don't even want to know at this point in time. Your answer is beautiful btw, I wish I could upvote it twice